# Wallpaper not properly fit on device screen, it either zoom or cropped

Tags: android, wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I created wallpaper app with glide using link images. I have three buttons to set image as wallpaper, lock-Screen and Home_Screen on device screen. But when I set this image as wallpaper its either zoom or cropped. I want image should fit on every android screen size.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button2:            

            Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            WallpaperManager manager1 = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                manager1.setBitmap(bitmap1, null, false, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set HomeScreen Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button3:              

            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            WallpaperManager manager2 = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                manager2.setBitmap(bitmap2, null, false, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set LockScreen Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button4:               

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set Wallpaper Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please help me????????

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73663041/9057721